# How to solve 'The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm does not handle bound constraints' error

Tags: algorithm, matlab, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to use LM Algorithm to optimize using lsqnonlin instead of interior-point to allow for gradient free optimization. However I get the following error

```
Error using lsqncommon (line 64)
The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm does not handle bound constraints and the trust-region-reflective algorithm requires at least as
many equations as variables; aborting.
```

Even though it is solved here as follows [1](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231135-error-in-lsqnonlin-line-232-error-in-lsqncommon-line-88), This says as LM algorithm can be modified to solve the problem in hand with boundaries[2](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/442037-handling-bound-constraints-by-the-levenberg-marquardt-algorithm). Is it possible to solve this error by modifying algorithm using lsqnonlin function?

Comment: Could you a share a code sample?

Comment: What you want is the trust-region version of the `lsqnonlin` but your cost function wrong for this (it probably returns only a single value?

Comment: have a look here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/239776-error-using-lsqncommon-line-67